# How to build a list of objects returned from querysets in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to return a list of objects which are returned in queryset for each id.

```
managers = Managers.objects.filter(project_id=project.id).extra(order_by=('id',))
manager_ids = [manager.id for manager in managers]  --> ['0', '1', '2']
members = Staff.objects.filter(manager_id=manager_ids[0]).extra(order_by=('id',))
...
return render(
    'project': project,
    'managers': managers, 
    'members': members <!-- this has to be a list of Member objects
```

The Managers queryset returns a list of managers related to the project and the Staff queryset will return the team members to each manager. The team members to each member has to be passed to render. How can I implement this?

Comment: You don't need to do this. You should follow the relationships when iterating in the template.

Comment: `list(members)`. But you really don't need to do it.

Comment: Is that simple? Thanks.